# Delphi 7 SOAP application stops compiling

Tags: delphi, soap

I don't know why, but a SOAP Server application and a pair of clients of this services stop compiling without any know causes for me. I have installed delphi 2007 and delphi 2009 and I don't know if the cause can come from this.

Now when I compile a soap application I get an error like:

> Unit XMLSchema was compiled with a different version of XMLDOM.SHttp

Someone known the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the dcus and try a build all. 
In case your compile with both d2007 and D2009, be sure to have different folders for the compiled code...
Make sure also that you don't have a "mixmatch" of D2007 and d2009 path to reference the used units.

Answer (score 2):

At end I found where was the problem. This come from a free library from codebot.org which contains another version of xmldom.pas

Thank you and regards

P.D. I will try to refund my accounts.